# Clarification on the weak BSD conjecture

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, elliptic-curves, birch-swinnerton-dyer

It is usually told that Birch and Swinnerton-Dyer developped their famous conjecture after studying the growth of the function
$$
f_E(x) = \prod_{p \le x}\frac{|E(\mathbb{F}_p)|}{p}
$$
as $x$ tends to $+\infty$ for elliptic curves $E$ defined over $\mathbb{Q}$, where the product is defined for the primes $p$ where $E$ has good reduction at $p$. Namely, this function should grow at the order of
$$
\log(x)^r
$$
when $x$ tends to $+\infty$, where $r$ is the (algebraic) rank of $E$.

**Question 1.** Why is it natural to look at these kind of products?

Nowadays, people usually state the BSD conjecture as the equality
$$
r = \text{ord}_{s=1}L(E,s)\text{.}
$$

**Question 2.** Are these two statements equivalent?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In regards to question 2, in 1982 Goldfeld proved that if $f_{E}(x) \sim C (\log x)^{r}$, then (i) $L(E,s)$ has no zeroes with ${\rm Re}(s) > 1$, and (ii) the order of vanishing at $L(E,s)$ is equal to $r$. I do not know if the converse is true (even assuming GRH for $L(E,s)$), as I don't have a copy of Goldfeld's paper.

Strangely, in the case that $r = 0$, Goldfeld shows that $C = \sqrt{2}/L(E,1)$.

Comment: Regarding the converse: Let $\alpha_p$ and $\beta_p$ be the Frobenius eigenvalues and set $\psi_E(x) = \sum_{p^k < x} (\alpha_p^k + \beta_p^k) \log p$. Keith Conrad http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/articles/eulerprod.pdf (Theorem 1.3) shows that $f_E(x) \sim C (\log x)^r$ is equivalent to (ii) together with $\psi_E(x) = o(x \log x)$, while GRH is equivalent to $\psi_E(x) = O(x (\log x)^2)$, so the Euler product condition appears stronger. (Of course, it is possible someone could find some bootstrapping argument which shows the $o(x \log x)$ and $O(x (\log x)^2)$ bounds are equivalent.)

Comment: In general, Keith's paper is very clear and pretty; I recommend it.

Comment: See also Kuo and Murty http://www.mast.queensu.ca/~murty/Kuo-Murty-CJM.pdf

Comment: K. Conrad also wrote an answer [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/25360) related to these results.

Answer (score 10):

I believe that the original experimental observation was that the product seems to converge to $\infty$ if $E(\mathbb Q)$ is infinite, and to a finite value if $E(\mathbb Q)$ is finite. Also, I may be mis-remembering, but I thought they looked at $$\prod_p \frac{p}{\#E(\mathbb F_p)},$$ with the limit conjecturally being $0$ if and only if $\#E(\mathbb Q)=\infty$.

Here's an intuitive reason to study this quantity. We know from Hasse that $\#E(\mathbb F_p)=p+1-a_p$ with $|a_p|\le2\sqrt p$. So
$$\log \left(\prod_p \frac{\#E(\mathbb F_p)}{p} \right)\approx -\sum_p \frac{a_p}{p}.$$ (This is just a heuristic, of course.) Anyway, this quantity diverges to $+\infty$ if the $a_p$ tend to be negative more often than they are positive. So one expects the product to equal $\infty$ if and only if $\#E(\mathbb F_p)$ is biased towards being larger than its "expected" value of $p+1$. On the other hand, if $E(\mathbb Q)=\infty$, then one might hope (guess?) that the image of $E(\mathbb Q)$ in $E(\mathbb F_p)$ tends to make $E(\mathbb F_p)$ somewhat larger than would be expected at random. Ergo, one expects that the product is large if and only if $E(\mathbb Q)$ is large. Then one does experiments to see whether "large" means "infinite".

Answer (score 6):

I recommend you to look at Birch and Swinnerton-Dyer's second paper (Notes on elliptic curves II). They explain beautifully the background for their conjecture.

The basic idea is that if you can prove that $L_E$ has an analytic continuation beyond $\Re(s)=3/2$ (Hasse-Weil conjecture), then

$$L_E(1)=\prod_p\bigg(\frac{|E(\mathbb{F}_p)|}{p}\bigg)^{-1}$$

In their paper they also mention:

> After the work of Siegel [19] on quadratic forms, it is natural to look at
>   the product $\prod N_p/p$ where $N_p$ is the number of rational points
>   on the curve over the finite field of $p$ elements.
>
> [19] *C. L. Siegel, Über die analytische Theorie der quadratischen Formen. I, II, III. Ann. of Math. 36 (1935), 37 (1936), 38 (1937).*

This is explained in more detail at the beginning of their first paper.

> Siegel has shown that the density of rational points on a quadric
>   surface can be expressed in terms of the densities of $p$-adic points;
>   which for almost all primes $p$ depends directly on the number of
>   solutions of the corresponding equation in the finite field with $p$
>   elements.
>
> It is natural to hope that something similar will happen for the
>   elliptic curve $$\Gamma:y^2=x^3-Ax-B$$where $A,B$ are rational
>   numbers.

Answer (score 3):

Question 1: The $L$-functon $L(E/\mathbf{Q},s)$ is a product over $L_p(E/\mathbf{Q},s) := 1/(1-a_pp^{-s}+p^{1-2s})$. Now plug in $s=1$ and use $p+1 - |E(\mathbf{F}_p)| = a_p$. (This is only a heuristic.)

Answer (score 3):

If $E$ is an elliptic curve over $\mathbf{Q}$, define $L_p(E,s) = \frac{1}{1-ap^{-s} + p^{1-2s}}$, where $a$ is $p-(|E_p(\mathbf{F}_p)| - 1)$. The L-function of E is defined as the product over the $L_p(E,s)$ over all primes not dividing $2\Delta$ (called “good primes”):
$$ L(E,s) = \prod_{p} L_p(E,s)$$
Since we wish to look at $L(E,1)$, we notice that $\displaystyle L_p(E,1) = \frac{p}{p+1-a}$. From the definition of $a$, we see that $p+1-a=|E_p(\mathbf{F}_p)|$, and so $\displaystyle L_p(E,1) = \frac{p}{|E_p(\mathbf{F}_p)|}$. Taking the product over all good primes $p$ shows that
$$L(E,1) = \prod_{p}\frac{p}{|E_p(\mathbf{F}_p)|}.$$

Comment: Apologies if this is a dumb question, but which parts of what you have written are conjectural? That is, are all the equals sign actually known identities?

Comment: @YemonChoi I was addressing the first question. None of the equalities are conjectural.